# configuring babel.config.js on react native project

Tags: react-native, babeljs

I need to configure my babel.config.js to use react-native-vision-camera as:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      {
        globals: ['__scanCodes'],
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

but my current configuration is as:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    'nativewind/babel',
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        extensions: [
          '.ios.ts',
          '.android.ts',
          '.ts',
          '.ios.tsx',
          '.android.tsx',
          '.tsx',
          '.jsx',
          '.js',
          '.json',
        ],
        alias: {
          '^@src/(.+)': './src/\\1',
          '^@assets/(.+)': './src/assets/\\1',
          '^@components/(.+)': './src/components/\\1',
          '^@contexts/(.+)': './src/contexts/\\1',
          '^@models/(.+)': './src/models/\\1',
          '^@navigation/(.+)': './src/navigation/\\1',
          '^@screens/(.+)': './src/screens/\\1',
          '^@services/(.+)': './src/services/\\1',
          '^@utils/(.+)': './src/utils/\\1',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Where to put my globals?

All the configurations I have tried are not working

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the trick is that reanimated warns to use their plugin LAST!!

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    'nativewind/babel',
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        extensions: [
          '.ios.ts',
          '.android.ts',
          '.ts',
          '.ios.tsx',
          '.android.tsx',
          '.tsx',
          '.jsx',
          '.js',
          '.json',
        ],
        alias: {
          '^@src/(.+)': './src/\\1',
          '^@assets/(.+)': './src/assets/\\1',
          '^@components/(.+)': './src/components/\\1',
          '^@contexts/(.+)': './src/contexts/\\1',
          '^@models/(.+)': './src/models/\\1',
          '^@navigation/(.+)': './src/navigation/\\1',
          '^@screens/(.+)': './src/screens/\\1',
          '^@services/(.+)': './src/services/\\1',
          '^@utils/(.+)': './src/utils/\\1',
        },
      },
    ],
    [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      {
        globals: ['__scanCodes'],
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    'nativewind/babel',
    ['react-native-reanimated/plugin', 
      { 
         globals: ['__scanCodes'],
      }
    ],
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        extensions: [
          '.ios.ts',
          '.android.ts',
          '.ts',
          '.ios.tsx',
          '.android.tsx',
          '.tsx',
          '.jsx',
          '.js',
          '.json',
        ],
        alias: {
          '^@src/(.+)': './src/\\1',
          '^@assets/(.+)': './src/assets/\\1',
          '^@components/(.+)': './src/components/\\1',
          '^@contexts/(.+)': './src/contexts/\\1',
          '^@models/(.+)': './src/models/\\1',
          '^@navigation/(.+)': './src/navigation/\\1',
          '^@screens/(.+)': './src/screens/\\1',
          '^@services/(.+)': './src/services/\\1',
          '^@utils/(.+)': './src/utils/\\1',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Comment: try config like that, i think it work

Comment: check detail here https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/frame-processors/#what-are-frame-processors